# how to know the version of ionic that already created an existing app

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed ionic in 2016
npm install cordova ionic -g

I don't remember the version number that has been installed
when i try to install this year with the same command i get the message 
indicating that the node version is old.

I want to return to the old version to run my apps on it
how can i know which version my apps were built by?

now when i am in the directory of one of my projects and type ionic serve --lab

it gives me an error
bash:ionic:command not found.

Now i got the version 
but when i write the command to install it gives me this error below:[image]

Comment: for that you need to install latest ionic

Comment: I get the version of my old ionic but when i write this command

Comment: which command please tell me?

Comment: npm install -g cordova@4.2.0 ionic@1.3.2

Comment: Okk i got it man